# Python how to find a linear line in a list of integer values?

Tags: python, list, line

I have a list of values

```
l = [ 54 , 53 , 52 , 51 , 20 , 49 , 48 , 105 , 46 , 45 ]
```

Are there any known algorithms that could find the linear line here?

```
linear_line = [ 54 , 53 , 52 , 51 , 50 , 49 , 48 , 47 , 46 , 45 ]
```

Comment: [Have a look at this link](http://blog.flip-edesign.com/?p=16)

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want?  Say the list were `[0,1,2,3,10,11,12,13]`.  What would the "linear line" be?  (While examples are helpful, the problem is that they usually leave a problem wildly underspecified.  It looks sort of like you're just trying to remove outliers, but it's hard to be sure.)

Comment: What is a 'linear line'? Are there non-linear lines? I'm unclear about what you want. Do you want to find ordered, sequential subsets of numbers in a list? What if there are multiple such subsets? Do you want all of them (e.g. l = [1,2,3,100,101]) ?

Comment: In the `linear_line` list, how did 47 get in there?

Comment: I think you might be looking for "linear regression". I would suggest Googling for libraries along those lines (maybe numpy or scipy has something?).

Comment: Linear regression is pretty hard in this case, since the two outliers act as leverage points and even a robust estimation might get mislead. RANSAC would be a promising approach. But first the OP should refine the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

it is not that difficult:

## first check if your values are linear

**step 1**

find the change between the first and second element

```
diff = l[1] - l[0]
```

**step 2**

check if for every 0

```
for i in range(1,len(l)):
    if (l[i] - l[i-1]) != diff :
        return false
return true
```

**to conclude**

```
def is_linear(l)
    diff = l[1] - l[0]
    for i in range(1,len(l)):
        if (l[i] - l[i-1]) != diff :
            return false
    return true
```

## secondly take a line between two points

I am assuming here that you want a line to the points (i, l[i])

**step 1**

find the slope: which is easy in the above assumption:

```
    slope = l[1] - l[0]
```

**step 2**

find the intercept with the y-axis, also easy in the above assumption
        yintercept = l[0]

**step 3**

the equation you search would be y = slope*x - yintercept.

if you want to be able to acces the elements, you'd do the following:

**step 4**

line = lambda x : slope*x - yintercept

## finally

if l is is linear you'll get:

```
0<i<len(l) implies line(i) == l[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import mode
l = np.array([ 54 , 53 , 52 , 51 , 20 , 49 , 48 , 105 , 46 , 45 ])
steps =l[1:]- l[:-1]
step,_ =  mode(steps)
print range(l[0],l[-1]+step,step)
```

that might do what you want ..

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution would be a [RANSAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC) approach:

```py
import numpy as np
import random

# define data points
y = np.array([ 54 , 53 , 52 , 51 , 20 , 49 , 48 , 105 , 46 , 45 ])

# initalize solution
max_count = 0
best_solution = None

# iteratively try samples
for iter in range(100):

    # choose two points
    i = random.choice(range(len(y)))
    j = random.choice(range(len(y)))
    if i == j:
        continue

    # compute line parameters
    m = (y[j] - y[i]) / (j - i)
    n = y[i] - i * m

    # compute coordinates of all data points
    y_ = m * np.arange(len(y)) + n

    # count support
    count = sum(y == y_)

    # update solution
    if count > max_count:
        max_count = count
        best_solution = y_

print best_solution, "supported by", max_count, "points"
```

This yields: `[54 53 52 51 50 49 48 47 46 45] supported by 8 points`. Note that the number of iterations depends on the amount of outliers. For this simple example 10 iterations might suffice as well.